# Python - Exporting Each Selected as FBX

Tags: python

Lets say I have 5 objects selected.  The script will correctly export 5 fbx files, place them at 0-0-0 world space, export an fbx with the object name, and return them to their original position.

The problem is that each export includes all selected objects instead of 1 at a time.  Shouldn't my for loop only grab each selected object 1 at a time?  How do I select 5 objects, export them so a single object is inside each fbx with the corresponding name?

```
    def execute(self, context):
        # Get the selected objects.
        selected = bpy.context.selected_objects
        for obj in selected:

            # Store current object's name.
            obj_name = obj.name

        # Get the object's original position.
        obj_loc_x = str(obj.location.x)
        obj_loc_y = str(obj.location.y)
        obj_loc_z = str(obj.location.z)

        # Creates the path for the exported fbx.
        obj_path = os.path.join(context.scene.worth_group_tools.dir_path,
                                obj_name + "." + "fbx")

        # Sends object to zero vectors.
        obj.location.x = 0.0
        obj.location.y = 0.0
        obj.location.z = 0.0

        # Export object as fbx. Works, except all selected objects are
        # exported into single fbx instead of one at a time from the list.
        bpy.ops.export_scene.fbx(filepath=obj_path, use_selection=True)

        # Prints each object in list.  Works.
        print(obj_name)

        # Returns the object to its original position.
        obj.location.x = float(obj_loc_x)
        obj.location.y = float(obj_loc_y)
        obj.location.z = float(obj_loc_z)

    return {'FINISHED'}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why your code below `obj_name = obj.name` is outside the *for-loop*? It should be in the same loop, isn't it?

#### Use `select_set()` for selection:

`obj.select_set(True)` : select the current object, useful for exporting selection.
You need to manually deselect it after exporting, or call `bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')` to deselect all.

### Minor things

#### Get the object's original position:

You can copy the location to a reference instead of casting it to string and convert it back.

`org_obj_loc = obj.location.copy()`

#### Sends object to zero vectors

You can assign a Vector() to it: `obj.location = (0,0,0)`

### Whole code

```py
def execute(self, context):
    for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects:
        bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
        obj.select_set(True)
        org_loc = obj.location.copy()

        # Sends object to zero vectors.
        obj.location = (0,0,0)

        # Creates the path for the exported fbx.
        obj_path = os.path.join(context.scene.worth_group_tools.dir_path,
                                obj.name + "." + "fbx")
        # Export object as fbx. Works, except all selected objects are
        # exported into single fbx instead of one at a time from the list.
        bpy.ops.export_scene.fbx(filepath=obj_path, use_selection=True)

        # Prints each object in list.  Works.
        print(obj.name)

        # Returns the object to its original position.
        obj.location = org_loc

return {'FINISHED'}
```

Comment: I apologize for the indention error.  It was correctly placed on my original code.  Thank you so much!  This works perfectly and is WAY cleaner.  I was unaware of the `obj.location.copy()` function.  Now everything makes sense!  Thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately I can't up-vote your solution.  Says I need at least 15 rep.  But this solution works!

Answer (score 1):

Great sample code!
I arranged it to be exported to the location where the Blender file is located.

> blender for 3.2

```
import bpy,os

def ShowMessageBox(message = "", title = "Output Fbx Success!", icon = 'INFO'):

    def draw(self, context):
        self.layout.label(text="Export file list")
        for conted, mes in enumerate(message,start=1):
            self.layout.label(text=str(conted) + "_" + mes.name)

    bpy.context.window_manager.popup_menu(draw, title = title, icon = icon)

    
def create_filepath(obj):       
        blnederfilepath = bpy.data.filepath
        directory = os.path.dirname(blnederfilepath)

        # Creates the path for the exported fbx.
        filepath = os.path.join(directory,
                                obj.name + "." + "fbx")
        return filepath

def fbx_export():
    
    seleobj=bpy.context.selected_objects
     
    for obj in seleobj:
        bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
        obj.select_set(True)
        org_loc = obj.location.copy()

        # Sends object to zero vectors.
        obj.location = (0,0,0)

        # Export object as fbx. Works, except all selected objects are
        filepath=create_filepath(obj)
        # exported into single fbx instead of one at a time from the list.
        bpy.ops.export_scene.fbx(filepath=filepath, use_selection=True)

        # Prints each object in list.  Works.
        # print(obj.name)

        # Returns the object to its original position.
        obj.location = org_loc

    ShowMessageBox(message= seleobj)    

fbx_export()
```